# Google play not recognizing email address (internal testing)

Tags: google-play, expo, google-play-internal-testing

I have setup my app for internal testing but every email address I type in, it seems as invalid. Including one of my own gmail accounts

[image]

Now the messed up part is that if I type in excel and import it as a CSV it will upload it the email but when I try to download the app via the weblink it says that I'm not part of the testers (yes I'm logged into that email address account). It won't let me do it in an incognito, on my computer, or on my phone. What is going on here?

[image]

Comment: Try to log out of all the other mails that you are logged in

Comment: still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you see I have a comma at the end of the email? You have to delete that and then it will submit. Othet issues can be solved by logging out of all of the other Gmail accounts